# USB 3.0 Harddrive is unresponsive for several seconds occasionally

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I changed my PC setup recently. Now I have some problems with a 1TB external 2.5" harddrive. It worked without problems before.
In the old setup it was plugged into a front USB 3.0 port. After changing the setup I plugged it into an USB 3.0 port on the back (might be the reason or the issue was introduced with an update).
Since then I get lags for about 10-20 seconds every now and then when accessing the drive (watching a movie or playing music).

I experience the same issues on a second PC, also attached to a rear USB 3.0 port.

I searched for help in a forum and now I know that there is a message in dmesg after the problem occurs:

```
usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

Immediately after this message appears everything is working normal again.

Unfortunately I don't know what causes the problem. So I hope someone can help.

Comment: possibly a problem with your hard drive?

Comment: Might be possible, would be an unlikely coincidence.

Comment: One thing I can think of to do is to plug it back into the front and see what happens. But because you said you tried two different computers and the same thing happened, this makes me wonder if there is something wrong with the hard drive...bad sector, read/write head getting stuck... something like that...also another thing you could try is another USB 3.0 HDD and see if you experience the same issues.

Comment: I will try plugging it into the front. I also have other HDDs, but 3.5" and didn't notice a problem with them (but I also use them pretty rarely).

Comment: I have the HDD attached to the front again. Had a 45 min video running in the background, but without problems according to dmesg

Comment: That is very interesting...maybe something with the USB port? Did you try another port on the back? Just trying to eliminate all the possibilities...

Comment: No, I did not try a different port on the back. But as I wrote, I experience the same problem on a second PC, so that is probably the same as trying a different port.